# Microsoft oauth account selection defaults to last used account even when multiple accounts are available

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm using Microsoft OAuth2 to get access token for my app. The normal Oauth flow works fine but if I have multiple accounts it always defaults to the last used account without letting me choose an account even if it's available in the list.

The only alternative I can think of is to use `prompt=login` but thats too intrusive, especially for every login.

My oauth urls

**Auth request**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<myAppId>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<myUrl>&scope=User.Read&state=1111`

**Token request**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?client_id=<myAppId>&client_secret=<myAppSecret>&redirect_uri=<myUrl>&code=<codeFromPreviousCall>&grant_type=authorization_code`

Is there a param that can be set to make user select an account?

Please see the gif below and note that I'm not clicking on any account in the second page [image: Microsoft Account selection]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `prompt=select_account`.

> select_account: The user is prompted to select an account,
>   interrupting single sign on. The user may select an existing signed-in
>   account, enter their credentials for a remembered account, or choose
>   to use a different account altogether.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, its not in the documentation though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: @Manoj. You can find it in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) by now.

Answer (score -1):

INCLUDE 'prompt' => 'select_account' TO THE PARAMETERS OF THE REQUEST

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).